# Save button didnt working

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Can somebody help me? I tried to make save button, but when I saved it, It don't do anything.

```
private void btnSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        try {
            String food_id = txtFoodID.getText();
            ButtonModel food_type = btngType.getSelection();
            String food_cat = cmbCat.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String food_name = txtFoodName.getText();
            String food_price = txtPrice.getText();

            Statement stmt;
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate("insert into menu_food values" + "('" + food_id + "','" + food_type + "','" + food_cat + "','" + food_name + "','" + food_price + "')");

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data saved",
                    "Message", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            txtFoodID.setText("");
            btngType.setSelected("");
            cmbCat.setSelectedItem("");
            txtFoodName.setText("");
            txtPrice.setText("");

        } catch (SQLException e) {

        }
    }
```

Here's my save function. Am I wrong use combo box or radio button function? please help me

[image: database]

[image]

when I click save, nothing happens

Comment: did it throw any error

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala no. nothing happens ._. So, that make me confused

Comment: can you try to print the values of individual fields like food_cat, food_type etc.

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala no ._.

Comment: Firstly, check if you are getting the values from the client to the server. Secondly, **close you Statement and connection objects**.

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala already. But same like before ._.

Comment: Don't you have to specify the column names in the insert statement? Like `insert into menu_food (food_id, food_type, food_cat, food_name,food_price) values ('" + food_id + "','" + food_type + "','" + food_cat + "','" + food_name + "','" + food_price + "')`

Comment: Ah! Thank you @SaagarEliasJacky. Can I ask one thing? The `food_type` still not working, can you see the coding, it is right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you have to specify the column names in the insert statement? Like

```
insert into menu_food 
             ( food_id
             , food_type
             , food_cat
             , food_name
             , food_price) 
      values ('" + food_id + "'
             ,'" + food_type + "'
             ,'" + food_cat + "'
             ,'" + food_name + "'
             ,'" + food_price + "')
```

and shouldn't this

```
    ButtonModel food_type = btngType.getSelection();
```

be

```
    String food_type = btngType.getSelection().getActionCommand();
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you! One more >< how about setSelected? Because it must use boolean, and I dont understand hehe ._. please

Comment: @enjeru you need to use an `if...else...` statement for that. If the type is Dish then `btnDish.setSelected(true);`